# Fastest way to loop through a CSV file and extract data in Delphi

Tags: multithreading, loops, for-loop, delphi, delphi-multithreading

I have a CSV file with over 10 million rows in it and I need to extract a certain column from the CSV file and save the value of all those rows for that column into a text file separated by a comma.

I've written some code to do this, but it's extremely slow. I ran it once and it took more than a day to complete.

Here's an example of the CSV file:

```
"1","facebook.com","10.00"
"2","fonts.googleapis.com","10.00"
"3","google.com","10.00"
"4","youtube.com","10.00"
"5","twitter.com","10.00"
"6","instagram.com","10.00"
"7","googletagmanager.com","10.00"
"8","linkedin.com","10.00"
"9","fonts.gstatic.com","10.00"
"10","gmpg.org","10.00"
"11","ajax.googleapis.com","9.47"
"12","maps.google.com","9.21"
"13","youtu.be","9.09"
"14","support.google.com","9.04"
"15","wordpress.org","9.01"
"16","cdnjs.cloudflare.com","9.01"
"17","play.google.com","9.00"
"18","plus.google.com","8.97"
"19","en.wikipedia.org","8.91"
"20","pinterest.com","8.81"
"21","docs.google.com","8.64"
"22","drive.google.com","8.64"
"23","s.w.org","8.59"
"24","bit.ly","8.53"
"25","github.com","8.50"
"26","goo.gl","8.49"
"27","secure.gravatar.com","8.45"
"28","amazon.com","8.39"
"29","itunes.apple.com","8.38"
"30","vimeo.com","8.38"
"31","developers.google.com","8.36"
"32","policies.google.com","8.31"
"33","vk.com","8.20"
"34","accounts.google.com","8.17"
"35","t.co","8.12"
"36","medium.com","8.10"
"37","flickr.com","8.09"
"38","creativecommons.org","8.07"
"39","w3.org","8.06"
"40","reddit.com","8.05"
"41","code.jquery.com","8.02"
"42","ec.europa.eu","7.98"
"43","gstatic.com","7.97"
"44","google-analytics.com","7.95"
"45","soundcloud.com","7.93"
```

I want to grab the second column in the CSV file and put that into a text file. Here's an example of the output:

```
facebook.com,fonts.googleapis.com,google.com,youtube.com,twitter.com,instagram.com,googletagmanager.com,linkedin.com,fonts.gstatic.com,gmpg.org,ajax.googleapis.com,maps.google.com,youtu.be,support.google.com,wordpress.org,cdnjs.cloudflare.com,play.google.com,plus.google.com,en.wikipedia.org,pinterest.com,docs.google.com,drive.google.com,s.w.org,bit.ly,github.com,goo.gl,secure.gravatar.com,amazon.com,itunes.apple.com,vimeo.com,developers.google.com,policies.google.com,vk.com,accounts.google.com,t.co,medium.com,flickr.com,creativecommons.org,w3.org,reddit.com,code.jquery.com,ec.europa.eu,gstatic.com,google-analytics.com,soundcloud.com,
```

And lastly, here's the code I wrote to do this. It works, but it's slow as hell:

```
begin
  var sites := 'D:\Downloads\domains.csv';
  var sitesList := TStringList.Create;
  sitesList.LoadFromFile(sites);


  var sitesNewList := TStringList.Create;
  for var I in sitesList do
  begin
    sitesNewList.Text := Trim(sitesNewList.Text) +
                         I.Substring(I.IndexOf(',')+2,(I.LastIndexOf(',')-I.IndexOf(','))-3) +
                         ',';
  end;

  sitesNewList.SaveToFile(TPath.ChangeExtension(sites,'txt'));
  sitesNewList.Free;

  sitesList.Free;
end;
```

---

What's the fastest way to achieve this? How can I loop through 10 million+ rows and extract the second column as quickly as possible?

Comment: @AdesojiAlu That actually worked really well. Thank you! 10min and it was finished. Please post an actual answer. Another question though: Is it possible to speed it up even more? Your solution only uses 10% of my CPU.

Comment: i would have to research more to see that the cpu % is less than 10%, i am glad it helped, kindly mark the answer while i do more research on this

Comment: @AdesojiAlu Single-threaded algorithm can only load one CPU core, so if you have a multi-core CPU, you will see that overall CPU usage is low (hence the 10%). Another potential bottleneck is disk I/O, which can be avoided by using buffered streams or switching to TMemoryStream.

Comment: If you are building product and the rest is in Delphi this makes sense. If your code is transient then why reinvent the wheel. This could be parsed in hardly any time using a good scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of a benchmark test adapted to pascal a few months ago - which [I detailed in a blog post](https://blog.synopse.info/?post/2022/11/26/Modern-Pascal-is-Still-in-the-Race).

I ended up writing a small CSV parser in *mORMot*, which could help you about performance.

The source code of the HTTP server using 80MB of CSV as source [is available
in github](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot2/blob/master/ex/lang-cmp/LangCmp.dpr).

You define the fields as a dynamic record:

```
type
  // high-level data structures with RawUtf8 (interned) values
  TStopTime = record
    TripID, StopID, Arrival, Departure: RawUtf8;
  end;
  TStopTimes = array of TStopTime;

  TTrip = record
    RouteID, TripID, ServiceID: RawUtf8;
  end;
  TTrips = array of TTrip;
```

Then you can use those structures with a `TDynArray` wrapper, to quickly load them with the `TDynArrayLoadCsv()` fast function.

```
  procedure TScheduler.GetStopTimes;
  var
    start: Int64;
    csv: RawUtf8;
  begin
    QueryPerformanceMicroSeconds(start);
    stopTimes.InitSpecific(TypeInfo(TStopTimes), stopTime, ptRawUtf8);
    csv := StringFromFile(NormalizeFileName('../MBTA_GTFS/stop_times.txt'));
    TDynArrayLoadCsv(stopTimes, pointer(csv), intern);
    stopTimes.EnsureSorted; // sort by first ptRawUtf8 field = TripID
    ConsoleWrite('parsed % stop times in %', [length(stopTime), MicroSecFrom(start)]);
  end;
```

If you want to extract only one column, just define one field in your record, with the proper name. The other columns will be ignored.

Here is [how the CSV parsing function is implemented](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot2/blob/master/src/core/mormot.core.search.pas#L3434) - you see it parses the input memory directly, and extract the values.

You may directly call the low-level `UnQuoteSqlStringVar()` function of mORMot in a dedicated loop, if you need even faster parsing with no dynamic array involved.